# Как прописать левый сайдбар на WP на странице "Каталог"

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток.Пользуюсь темой mystile. Нагуглил видео,где видно,что на странице "Товары" есть левый сайдбар.У меня к сожалению его нету,хотя на других страницах он есть.
Через какой файл можно его добавить и как.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках самой темы есть соответствующие галочки для WooCommerce

[image: показывать или нет сайдбар]

Comment: Да,ты почти прав,я там не включил и еще в админке есть вкладка,которая позволяет включить/выключить сайдбар на странице "каталог".В этих двух местах нужно было включить.
Благодарю за ответ)